# Retornar lista através de uma data específica

Tags: visual-basic-6

Em seguimento de um projeto que estou a desenvolver, ocorreu-me uma situação na qual não consigo solucionar.

O objetivo desta pergunta é saber como faço para obter num determinado dia o número de requisições que a biblioteca de uma escola faz.
Até aí tudo bem, esse problema está resolvido.

Agora, surgiu-me uma nova ideia mas que está difícil de resolver e é a seguinte: eu queria na mesma fazer o que referi em cima, mas através do `datetimepicker` escolher o dia e aparecer através de uma busca na base de dados saber se as requisições desse dia.

Em baixo irei deixar prints do código que tenho neste momento e as respectivas forms.

Este é o `select` utilizado para já:

```
SELECT Requisição.codRequisicao,
       Requisição.dataRequisicao,
       Utilizadores.numProcesso,
       Utilizadores.nomeUtilizador,
       Turma.Ano,
       Turma.Turma,
       Turma.Curso,
       TpUtilizador.Descricao,
       TipoServiço.descricaoTpServico
FROM Requisição
INNER JOIN TipoServiço ON Requisição.codTpServico = TipoServiço.codTpServico
INNER JOIN Utilizadores ON Requisição.numProcesso = Utilizadores.numProcesso
INNER JOIN Turma ON Utilizadores.codTurma = Turma.codTurma
INNER JOIN TpUtilizador ON Utilizadores.CodUtilizador = TpUtilizador.CodUtilizador
WHERE (Requisição.dataRequisicao >= CONVERT(date, GETDATE()))
```

Por exemplo no dia 26/06/2015 determinada pessoa fez uma requisição:

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Aqui é onde se registam as requisições:

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Comment: eu vi sua edição na minha resposta, seu erro está no primeiro parênteses antes do `CONVERT` remova-a de tal forma que fique igual a minha resposta

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No seu `SELECT` vai existir um problema que é o `>=` quando você for procurar datas anteriores a de hoje, por exemplo se quiser de ontem vai aparecer ontem e hoje pois é **maior ou igual**.

Pra resolver isso do `>=`, só comparar **igual** eliminando as horas, exemplo:

```
WHERE CONVERT(date, Requisição.dataRequisicao) = CONVERT(date, GETDATE()))
```

Ficando

```
SELECT Requisição.codRequisicao,
       Requisição.dataRequisicao,
       Utilizadores.numProcesso,
       Utilizadores.nomeUtilizador,
       Turma.Ano,
       Turma.Turma,
       Turma.Curso,
       TpUtilizador.Descricao,
       TipoServiço.descricaoTpServico
FROM Requisição
INNER JOIN TipoServiço ON Requisição.codTpServico = TipoServiço.codTpServico
INNER JOIN Utilizadores ON Requisição.numProcesso = Utilizadores.numProcesso
INNER JOIN Turma ON Utilizadores.codTurma = Turma.codTurma
INNER JOIN TpUtilizador ON Utilizadores.CodUtilizador = TpUtilizador.CodUtilizador
WHERE CONVERT(date, Requisição.dataRequisicao) = CONVERT(date, GETDATE()))
```

E no seu caso com o `DateTimePicker`, acredito que dê pra fazer algo assim:

```
Dim strSQL As String = "SELECT... " + 
                       "WHERE CONVERT(date, Requisição.dataRequisicao) = @dataEscolhida "
Using con = new SqlConnection("datasource...")
    con.Open()
    Using cmd = new SqlCommand(strSQL, con)
        cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@dataEscolhida", DateTimePicker1.Value)

        ' executeReader
    End Using
End Using
```

Comment: "Operand type clash: date is incompatible with int" dá-me este erro

Comment: tenta colocar `DateTimePicker1.Value` direto, sem .ToString(), eu nunca fiz esse teste com datas na query pra saber qual melhor forma

Comment: Você ta utilizando `SqlCommand` né?

Comment: Exatamente. Continua a dar erro de sintaxe.

Comment: @Forrobodo Da uma olhada na resposta atualizada

Comment: o que é a @dataEscolhida?

Comment: No strSQL é um parâmetro, depois no `cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue` você adiciona valor a esse parâmetro, por quê?

Comment: Nao estou a entender desculpe

Comment: Vamos [continuar esta discussão no chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/25244/discussion-between-maicon-carraro-and-forrobodo).